# Abstracting from Stateful object navigation (1-1) - the challenge

Tags: c#, .net, oop

The point of this exercise is to make navigation between objects stateful.

For example, having Person and Address with 1-1 association it should:

- If an address is assigned to a persons, then the person should be assigned to the address (and vice versa).
- If address is assigned to person1 and then to person2, then the person1 will have no address and person2 will.

---

This is the piece of code that implements it.

```
public class A {
    internal B a;
    public B Value {
        get {
            return a;
        }
        set {
            if (value == null) {
                if (a != null)
                    a.a = null;
            }  else
                value.a = this;
            a = value;
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    internal A a;
    public A Value {
        get {
            return a;
        }
        set {
            if (value == null) {
                if (a != null)
                    a.a = null;
            }  else
                value.a = this;
            a = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows following tests to pass:

```
// For the common setup:
var a = new A();
var b = new B();

// Test 1:
a.Value = b;
Assert.AreSame(a, b.Value);

// Test 2:
b.Value = a;
Assert.AreEqual(b, a.Value);

// Test 3:
b.Value = a;
b.Value = null;
Assert.IsNull(a.Value);

// Test 4:
var a2 = new A();
b.Value = a2;
Assert.AreSame(b, a2.Value);
Assert.AreNotSame(a, b.Value);

// Test 5:
a.Value = b;
Assert.AreSame(a, b.Value);
var a1 = new A();
var b1 = new B();
a1.Value = b1;
Assert.AreSame(a1, b1.Value);

// Test 6:
var a1 = new A();
var b1 = new B();
Assert.IsNull(a.Value);
Assert.IsNull(b.Value);
Assert.IsNull(a1.Value);
Assert.IsNull(b1.Value);
```

---

Now the question is: how would you abstract the code in the setters to avoid possible mistakes when writing a lot of such classes?

The conditions are:

- The PUBLIC interfaces of classes A and B cannot be changed.
- Factories should not be used.
- Statics should not be used (to persist shared info).
- ThreadInfo or similar should not be used.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: Yes. Pass the tests. I updated the question to explicitly ask that :)

Comment: You say above that you're challenging yourself; so, please show us what you've tried and we can try to put you onto the right paths if you've become stuck somewhere. Otherwise you're challenging the community.

Comment: @overslacked, I've updated the question (see Link class) for what I've come up with.

Comment: @leppie, Test 4 is just a guard to prevent using static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your challenge. What happens when you instantiate a few instances of class A and then a single instance of class B?

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
A a3 = new A();
A a4 = new A();
A a5 = new A();
B b = new B();
```

Which test passes? Which one fails?

You see, once `A` is instantiated, it has a **state**. This state should be somehow involved with an instance of `B`, an **existing instance**. So this instance of `B` must exist even before you instantiate this `A` class.

The same is true for an instance of `B`. It should hold a reference to an already existing instance of `A`.

As far as I understand, class A should have a constructor with a reference to an existing instance of B:

```
public class A
{
    private B b;
    public A(B b)
    {
          this.b = b;
    }
}

// Then you can have:
B b1 = new B();
A a1 = new A(b1); // here's the link

B b2 = new B();
A a2 = new A(b2); // and another link
```

Either this or the other way around with `B`.

You write that you don't want to change the public signatures of `A` and `B`, and you don't want to add factories to the code. I really can't see a consistent solution under such constraints. Or maybe the challenge itself is not clear enough?

EDIT: Taking a wild guess here, I think that what you try to achieve here can be done using Reflection: you might want to reflect existing code up to a point (in the call stack), and match a new instance of, say, `A` to an existing instance of `B`. This is **can** be done using reflection, but it's pretty hard and you must have a concrete and robust set of rules for the linkage between new instances of `A`s and `B`s. If this **is** the direction of the needed solution, then I think you should dive into reflection and see how it goes, it's a huge field.

Comment: Ron, I have updated the question a bit to give an example so hopefully it will clarify things a bit. And added test 6 that shows how objects should behave if there are many of them.

ATM, it sounds like under the constrains there is actually no obvious solution.